# App Crashing Upon Saving Update

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having some issues with an app I am creating, the problem arises when I click the save button when updating a record.

Here is my Java file.

```
import com.androidadvance.db.DatabaseHelper;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddUpdateValues extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button btn_updaterecord;
    private EditText txtpname, txtpprice;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    ProductModel pm;
    Intent i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addupdatevalues);

        i = getIntent();

        txtpname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_udatepname);
        txtpprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_udatepprice);

        txtpname.setText(i.getExtras().getString("name"));
        txtpprice.setText(i.getExtras().getString("price"));
        btn_updaterecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_updaterecord);
        btn_updaterecord.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_updaterecord:
            if (txtpname.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || txtpprice.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(AddUpdateValues.this, "Please add values..",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                db.getWritableDatabase();
                pm = new ProductModel();
                pm.productname = txtpname.getText().toString();
                pm.productprice = txtpprice.getText().toString();
                pm.idno = i.getExtras().getString("id");

                Log.i(">>>>>productid<<<<<", "" + i.getExtras().getString("id"));
                db.updateProduct(pm);
                Toast.makeText(AddUpdateValues.this,
                        "Room Update successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                db.close();
                super.onResume();

            }
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Update Room Length:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_udatepname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:hint="Room Length" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Update Room Width:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_udatepprice"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:hint="Room Width" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_updaterecord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Save Changes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Databasehelper

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import com.homediyassistant.screen.ProductModel;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static String DATABASENAME = "androidadvancesqlite";
    public static String PRODUCTTABLE = "products";
    public static String colProductId = "id";
    public static String _colProductid = "productidno";
    public static String colProductName = "productname";
    public static String colProductPrice = "productprice";
    private ArrayList<ProductModel> cartList = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();
    Context c;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, 33);
        c = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists " + PRODUCTTABLE + "("
        // + colProductId + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
        // + "productidno" + "TEXT," + colProductName + " TEXT ,"
        // + colProductPrice + " TEXT)");

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE if not exists producttable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + "productidno"
                + " TEXT ,"
                + "productname"
                + " TEXT,"
                + "productprice" + " TEXT)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + PRODUCTTABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addProduct(ProductModel productitem) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("productidno", productitem.idno);
        contentValues.put("productname", productitem.productname);
        contentValues.put("productprice", productitem.productprice);
        db.insert("producttable", null, contentValues);
        db.close();

    }

    // update

    public void updateProduct(ProductModel productList) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("productname", productList.productname);

        contentValues.put("productprice", productList.productprice);
        db.update("producttable", contentValues, "productidno="
                + productList.idno, null);

        db.close();
    }

    public void emptyProduct() {
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("delete from producttable");
            db.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeProduct(String productid, String pname, String pprice) {
        try {
            // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            // db.execSQL("delete from producttable where productidno="
            // + productid);
            // db.close();

            String[] args = { productid };
            getWritableDatabase().delete("producttable", "productidno=?", args);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ProductModel> getProudcts() {

        cartList.clear();

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from producttable", null);
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    ProductModel item = new ProductModel();

                    item.idno = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("productidno"));

                    item.productname = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("productname"));

                    item.productprice = cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex("productprice"));

                    cartList.add(item);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return cartList;
    }
}
```

Here is my logcat

```
05-03 12:10:09.323: E/SensorManager(3963): thread start
05-03 12:10:09.898: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:09.898: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:17.498: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:17.498: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:20.868: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:20.868: E/SpannableStringBuilder(3963): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:10:38.173: E/SQLiteLog(3963): (1) no such column: fff
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: fff (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE producttable SET productprice=?,productname=? WHERE productidno=fff
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1038)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:649)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1563)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1514)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.homediyassistant.db.DatabaseHelper.updateProduct(DatabaseHelper.java:68)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.homediyassistant.screen.AddUpdateValues.onClick(AddUpdateValues.java:59)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17356)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-03 12:10:38.193: E/AndroidRuntime(3963):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I cannot put my finger on where it is falling down.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: share your stackTrace...

Comment: and your databasehelper

Comment: I have now added my databasehelper

Comment: what issues you are having???. post your logcat here

Comment: I'm still having problemms with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your logcat it seems that your app is getting crashed because you are entering an 'id' (productidno), which does not exist in the table. Either enter a valid 'id' or do a check for the 'id' that is being entered.

I hope this solves your problem.